# Docker abnormal stop and how can i let it “tell” me（using mail or others）

Tags: docker

When docker abnormal stop，we cannot find it for the first time.
Is there any way to send it to me by mail or at any other way when it stops?
I use shipyard to manage it，but it havanot this function.

Can I find a way to monitor docker accidentally stopped and send a notification to the user？

Answer (score 2):

The Docker Engine has an events subsystem that you can feed to the CLI or any Docker API client.

The simplest way to access is via the cli command: [`docker events`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/#extended-description). You get events for a whole lot of things, The `container` event you are probably interested in is `die` but also `kill`, `oom`, `pause`, and `stop` and `start` deal with the lifecycle. The `die` event contains an `exitCode` along with other metadata.

The following event log is from a `docker run debian sleep 180`.

- Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to try interrupt is the `kill signal=2`
- Running `docker stop` sends `kill signal=15`
- After 10 seconds the `docker stop` times out and sends `kill signal=9`
- Then the container dies with `exitCode=137`

Event log:

```
→ docker events \
    --filter event=start \
    --filter event=stop \
    --filter event=kill \
    --filter event=die \
    --filter event=oom \
    --filter event=pause

2017-09-27T05:28:22.911051215Z container start bb9998ef9ce04930588760edfbe3da0c3d505980df333906ae5fa1bcf847726e (image=debian, name=mystifying_fermi)
2017-09-27T05:28:25.852465665Z container kill bb9998ef9ce04930588760edfbe3da0c3d505980df333906ae5fa1bcf847726e (image=debian, name=mystifying_fermi, signal=2)
2017-09-27T05:28:42.500055815Z container kill bb9998ef9ce04930588760edfbe3da0c3d505980df333906ae5fa1bcf847726e (image=debian, name=mystifying_fermi, signal=15)
2017-09-27T05:28:52.502913619Z container kill bb9998ef9ce04930588760edfbe3da0c3d505980df333906ae5fa1bcf847726e (image=debian, name=mystifying_fermi, signal=9)
2017-09-27T05:28:52.603362125Z container die bb9998ef9ce04930588760edfbe3da0c3d505980df333906ae5fa1bcf847726e (exitCode=137, image=debian, name=mystifying_fermi)
2017-09-27T05:28:53.028998070Z container stop bb9998ef9ce04930588760edfbe3da0c3d505980df333906ae5fa1bcf847726e (image=debian, name=mystifying_fermi)
```

There's a pypi package [docker-event-scripts](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker-event-scripts) ([github](https://github.com/colebrumley/des)) that let's you run a script on a category/event. It's based on the `docker-py` library that is fairly widely used.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what the article "[Get Alerts When Docker Containers Run Into Issues](https://dzone.com/articles/get-alerts-when-docker-containers-run-into-issues) "

It proposes *not* to use Prometheus (a bit overkill for just that), but [**monitor-docker-slack**](https://github.com/DennyZhang/monitor-docker-slack)

[image: https://www.dennyzhang.com/wp-content/uploads/denny/monitor_docker_compose.png]

Comment: Had a quick look and that python monitor doesn't watch an event stream, it polls a `docker ps -a` on a configurable timeframe

Comment: but a bit more work! I didn't find a pre made container like that on my quick search.

Comment: @Matt Container? Shouldn't we consider a system outside docker anyway?

Comment: Yes, but I'd only see no container as a hard requirement if you can't heartbeat the monitor.

Comment: and no one creates a monitor without a heartbeat, right? :)

Comment: @Matt Right. The HEALTHCHECK command (https://blog.alexellis.io/test-drive-healthcheck/)